# Adding 1 to a week number if the week starts on Sunday In SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I actually want to **add 1** to a week number if it starts with Sunday. I was trying to write a case condition i.e.

```
SELECT DATEPART(week, '2022/10/30') -- which is a Sunday
```

The output I am getting is **44**

But I need the output as **45**

Thanks

Comment: MS (being American) assumes weeks are Sunday-Saturday. If you're in the majority of the rest of the world you'll want to have a look into DATEFIRST. Or you really want this conditional logic you can use DATEPART with DW which stands for Day of Week

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Seems like a simple use of IIF can do it

Comment: Perhaps investing in a Calendar table would be worth while for consistent behaviour.

Comment: What should "if the week starts on Sunday" mean? Do some of your weeks start on Sunday, some on Wednesday and some on Friday?